# Determining whether rows exist in a MySQL database already

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm receiving an error message that reads: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ... on line 45`

Stemming from this section of the code:

```
//Only allow the input of empty responses once
foreach ($questionIDs as $questionID) {
    $query = "SELECT response_id FROM quiz_response " .
    "WHERE question_id = '".$questionID."' AND user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}
if (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) == false) {
    // Create empty responses in 'quiz_response' table if none exist already
    foreach ($questionIDs as $questionID) {
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO quiz_response (user_id, question_id) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '" . $questionID . "')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    } 
}
```

Line 45 is `if (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) == false) {`

The script still works correctly, however, it produces the error message (above) on the page as well.  Basically, I'm trying to ensure that there aren't already columns associated with this particular user and question_id before creating rows for this user.  To do this I do a query of the table and if there aren't any rows matching the criteria I create them.

I'm drawing a blank on how to solve the issue.  I've tried a number of different ways and haven't had any success.  An outside perspective is needed... I appreciate any help or input.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop? You are running many queries but only remembering the result from the last one.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to figure out why the query is failing in the first place. I have one idea in particular though...

Comment: I'm thinking that $result is null and it's crashing because it's expecting that parameter to be a mysqli_result but it's a null object. Check that it's not null.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that you have [connected](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.mysqli-affected-rows.htm) to database using:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Then you try it like this, as pointed in comments on question your loop structure is inserting new record only for the last `$questionID` if it does not exists as the insertiion logic is outside the loop where you check existence of record:

```
//Only allow the input of empty responses once
foreach ($questionIDs as $questionID) {
    $query = "SELECT response_id FROM quiz_response " .
    "WHERE question_id = '".$questionID."' AND user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) == false) {
        // Create empty responses in 'quiz_response' table if none exist already
        foreach ($questionIDs as $questionID) {
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO quiz_response (user_id, question_id) 
            VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '" . $questionID . "')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
foreach ($questionIDs as $questionID) {
  $query = "SELECT response_id FROM quiz_response " .
    "WHERE question_id = '".$questionID . 
    "' AND user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  //using count to make sure that there are no existing records:
  $count = count($result);
  if ($count == 0) {
    // Create empty responses in 'quiz_response' table if none exist already
    foreach ($questionIDs as $questionID) {
      $query2 = "INSERT INTO quiz_response (user_id, question_id) 
        VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '" . $questionID . "')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The error is because your query is returning a null and it is not possible to fetch an array from a null query.

You also have a typo here:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

It should be:

```
$result = mysql_query($dbc, $query);
```

you have an extra i. That is what seems to be causing the problem.

Also, you have to do $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc); not the other way round.

Comment: errrm, what? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: it stands for `mysql improved` thus `mysqli`

Comment: oh man. never really used that. My apologies.